# How can I force a long string without any blank to be wrapped?

Tags: html, css, string, xul, word-wrap

I have a long string (a DNA sequence). It does not contain any whitespace character.

For example:

```
ACTGATCGAGCTGAAGCGCAGTGCGATGCTTCGATGATGCTGACGATGCTACGATGCGAGCATCTACGATCAGTCGATGTAGCTAGTAGCATGTAGTGA
```

What would be the CSS selector to force this text to be wrapped in a `html:textarea` or in a `xul:textbox`?

Comment: Ironically the string doesn't break in Stack Overflow either...

Answer (score 326, accepted):

for block elements:

```html
<textarea style="width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;">
  ACTGATCGAGCTGAAGCGCAGTGCGATGCTTCGATGATGCTGACGATGCTACGATGCGAGCATCTACGATCAGTC
</textarea>
```

for inline elements:

```html
<span style="width:100px; word-wrap:break-word; display:inline-block;"> 
   ACTGATCGAGCTGAAGCGCAGTGCGATGCTTCGATGATGCTGACGATGCTACGATGCGAGCATCTACGATCAGTC
</span>
```

Comment: It's supported only in IE, Safari, and FF3.1 (alpha).

Comment: just tested your solution with the last FF . Worked fine.

Comment: this works only in new wave of browsers - see http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break

Comment: @Michael: The answer uses the "word-wrap" rule, not the "word-break" one; the former is supported as used in [almost every browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap) used today. Where "partial support" is indicated, it appears that the "break-word" value for the "word-wrap" rule is still viable.

Comment: I don't think this solution works any longer. At least not in current Chrome.

Comment: The property got renamed to `overflow-wrap` since in the standards, but `wrod-wrap` is widely implemented.

Comment: It doesn't work. It breaks words in the middle of the word.

Comment: Also works with "display: table-cell", was necesary in my case

Comment: In case a predefined width is not desired, using `<span style="overflow-x:hidden; word-wrap:break-word;"> ` works too. (Firefox 58)

Comment: I needed `word-break: break-all` for this as mentioned in [emiks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18484181/1318694)

Comment: I needed `overflow-wrap: 'anywhere'`

Comment: now... the most relevant comments all refer to `overflow-wrap`... i upvoted each comment to try an draw more attention to them... `overflow-wrap:anywhere` did it for me

Answer (score 113):

Place [zero-width spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space) at the points where you want to allow breaks. The zero-width space is `&#8203;` in HTML. For example:

`ACTGATCG&#8203;AGCTGAAG&#8203;CGCAGTGC&#8203;GATGCTTC&#8203;GATGATGC`

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Was having a hard time getting something like this to work inside a table, and this solution is the only one that I found works in IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: +1, this works better as it covers more cases, even though question was for a more particular case.

Comment: You could alternatively use the `<wbr>` tag, which serves the same purpose of providing an optional line-break opportunity.

Comment: Watch if you do this in things that might be copied and pasted.

Comment: Regex `\s` (whitespace), doesn't match a zero-width space. If you want to remove them, you need to explicitly write `/\u200B/g` or similar. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes

Comment: Note: Some of us prefer to spell it in hex, as `&#x200B;`, so that we can find the Unicode reference (code U+200B) more easily.

Comment: This is very useful for wrapping inside HTML emails (if you are able to process text before rendering templates) without the headache of worrying about rendering logic in different email clients

Answer (score 53):

Here are some very useful answers:

[How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)

to save you time, this can be solved with css:

```
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
white-space: -hp-pre-wrap; /* HP printers */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */
white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: pre-wrap; /* CSS 2.1 */
white-space: pre-line; /* CSS 3 (and 2.1 as well, actually) */
word-wrap: break-word; /* IE */
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: +1 this because it mentions word-break:break-all; which worked for me in IE9

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` was the only one that worked in Android WebView for me.

Comment: Thank you for `word-break: break-all;`!

Comment: TIL there's a `-hp-` prefix!

Comment: It appears the `break-word` value for `word-wrap` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#values). Instead you can use [`overflow-wrap: anywhere`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) or `overflow-wrap: break-word`.

Answer (score 20):

For me this works,

```
<td width="170px" style="word-wrap:break-word;">
  <div style="width:140px;overflow:auto">
    LONGTEXTGOESHERELONGDIVGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESLONGTEXTGOESHERELONGDIVLONGTEXTLONGTEXT
  </div>
</td>
```

You can also use a div inside another  div instead of `td`. I used `overflow:auto`, as it shows all the text both in my Opera and IE browsers.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have to move "word-wrap" property into div and remove "overflow" property. With this changes, works.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think you can do this with CSS. Instead, at regular 'word lengths' along the string, insert an HTML soft-hyphen:

```
ACTGATCG&shy;AGCTGAAG&shy;CGCAGTGC&shy;GATGCTTC&shy;GATGATGC&shy;TGACGATG
```

This will display a hyphen at the end of the line, where it wraps, which may or may not be what you want.

Note Safari seems to wrap the long string in a `<textarea>` anyway, unlike Firefox.

Comment: Wow, didn't even know about that. Neat!

Comment: I did not know about that either. Double Neat!

Answer (score 12):

Use a CSS method to force wrap a string that has no white-spaces. Three methods:

1) Use the CSS white-space property. To cover browser inconsistencies, you have to declare it several ways. So just put your looooong string into some block level element (e.g., div, pre, p) and give that element the following css:

```
some_block_level_tag {
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */
}
```

2)  use the [force-wrap mixin from Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/text/force-wrap/).

3) I was just looking into this as well and I think might also work (but I need to test browser support more completely):

```
.break-me {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Reference: [wrapping content](http://perishablepress.com/wrapping-content/)

Comment: Yes, the #3 there works in all modern browsers and even older IE6+.

Comment: #3 only works if there are opportunities to break by words. An overly long string does not break ( tested on Chrome 52.0.2743.82 ).

Answer (score 9):

My way to go (when there is no appropiate way to insert special chars) via CSS:

```
-ms-word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
hyphens: auto;
```

As found here: http://kenneth.io/blog/2012/03/04/word-wrapping-hypernation-using-css/
with some additional research to be found there.

Answer (score 5):

For `word-wrap:break-word;` to work for me, I had to make sure the `display` was set to `block`, and that the width was set on the element. In Safari, it had to have a `p` tag and the `width` had to be set in `ex`.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)tag:

```
ACTGATCG<wbr>AGCTGAAG<wbr>CGCAGTGC<wbr>GATGCTTC<wbr>GATGATGC
```

I think this is better than using zero-width space `&#8203;` which could cause problems when you copy the text.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using PHP then the wordwrap function works well for this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

The CSS solution `word-wrap: break-word;` does not seem to be consistent across all browsers.

Other server-side languages have similar functions - or can be hand built.

Here's how the the PHP wordwrap function works:

```
$string = "ACTGATCGAGCTGAAGCGCAGTGCGATGCTTCGATGATGCTGACGATGCTACGATGCGAGCATCTACGATCAGTCGATGTAGCTAGTAGCATGTAGTGA";

$wrappedstring = wordwrap($string,50,"&lt;br&gt;",true);
```

This wraps the string at 50 characters with a <br> tag. The 'true' parameter forces the string to be cut.

Comment: You can mix this solution with Remy's solution to insert zero-width spaces:  wordwrap ($longtext, 5, "&#8203;", true);

Answer (score 3):

```
<textarea style="width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;">
  place your text here
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

In a case where the table isnt of fixed size, below line worked for me:

```
style="width:110px; word-break: break-all;"
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you use Bootstrap, better case for you is use this class "text-break".

Example:

`<p class="text-break">mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</p>`

More informationg you should get in official Bootstrap documentation page

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
word-break: break-word;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code I come into using `white-space: pre-wrap;`

```css
.code {
        width: 40vw;
        white-space: pre-wrap; 
        word-break: break-word;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;   
        border    : 1px solid darkgray;
    }
```

```html
<p class="code">ACTGATCGAGCTGAAGCGCAGTGCGATGCTTCGATGATGCTGACGATGCTACGATGCGAGCATCTACGATCAGTCGATGTAGCTAGTAGCATGTAGTGA</p>
```

I know the `width` value is looks odd, you should change it to value fits your needs .

Answer (score 1):

just setting `width` and adding `float` worked for me :-)

```
width:100%;
float:left;
```

Comment: It is a complete and easy answer i think that guy who posted this problem originally should use width:100%; with float:left; on element which contains that string and his problem will be resolved. then why is this answer not relevant?

Comment: because that guy who posted this problem don't think your solution worked five years ago.

Comment: Yes, but this forum is not only about that guy  only its about this forum and  other people facing similar problem like me today can also have benefit from the same.