# CSS Overflow auto

Tags: javascript, css, overflow

Hi i doing comment box in my webpage so that i am doing a validation of that comment box by not allowing the user to enter the empty comment, and a comment sholud not be greater than 255 characters it all working fine but when i enter the comment like this means

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaakjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
```

this string is overflowing out of the comment box div i.e it is going like a straight line 
I had used css property overflow: auto; but wat i need is it should be shown like this. it should split the string

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaakjjjjjjjjj
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
```

for ex: when i comment like this `The p element has both line boxes and a child box for the q element, which is a block-level element. The line boxes before the q are wrapped in an anonymous block-level box and so are the line boxes after the q. The resulting tree of boxes might be as fol`

it coming up proper ... it should like this

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your comment box?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: how can I force a long string (without any blank) to be wrapped in XUL and/or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/499137/css-how-can-i-force-a-long-string-without-any-blank-to-be-wrapped-in-xul-and-o)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is CSS `word-wrap: break-word;`. It is widely supported among browsers.

[word-wrap on CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/)

[word-wrap: break-word](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEbreak-word.html)

Comment: Won't word-wrap cause some problems with older browsers, being a CSS3 feature?

Comment: It was standardized in CSS3, though it has existed for a long time. http://caniuse.com/#search=word-wrap

Comment: Thanks for that. Ignore my answer, this is probably your best option. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 property to solve your question:

```
.text_wrap {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: How is this different from my earlier answer? :)

Comment: I just started type my answer before you answer was published and published my answer after you :)

Comment: Happens a lot to me either :).