# Can't break a long string/text, it exceeds the width of html div

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="id_div_comments"><p>body4qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</p></div><br/><br/>
</div>
```

The css file:

```
div#id_div_comments {
    width: 400px;
}
```

But the string/texts exceeds the division width.
What can i do to break the texts when it reaches the width of the division ?

Comment: Related thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258416/word-wrap-in-a-html-table/1258478#1258478

Comment: I found this solution better for most of the cases - http://stackoverflow.com/a/764015/2063659

Answer (score 34, accepted):

wirte this in your css `word-wrap:break-word;`
css:

```
#id_div_comments p{
 word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: The support for "word-wrap: break-word" is still buggy in most browsers, unfortunately. (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=249787&thanks=249787&ts=1371225408) It does work in simple cases, though. "overflow: auto" does not (nor is supposed to) break words at all, it just adds a scrollbar if needed

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
#id_div_comments p{
 white-space:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## The accepted answer doesn't work for me

After seaching around, the following css actually works

```
#id_div_comments p{
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Just trust me

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Old question but no correct answer, for long text this should work

```
#id_div_comments p{
 word-break: break-all;
}
```