# Why won't Google Chrome autobreak?

Tags: css, google-chrome, html, pre

I did something wrong in this document and I can´t figure what. I've not that much content yet. I'm building it for a WB. It's not working in Google Chrome but in Internet Explorer it is.

http://privat.bahnhof.se/wb802226/tesing.html

Could somebody look into the source code and look for an error?

I want to make the long `<span>` break. I want to make the `<span>` a `<pre>`. And I want the `<pre>` autobreaking aswell. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't this an unrealistic case? In which situation would you encounter such a long word/string with no space? Not even in finnish or deutsch AFAIK. Also, what is a WB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying `word-wrap: break-word;` to your div, it works for me on Chrome.

In case you want a more cross-browser solution, you can try placing zero-width spaces `&#8203;` in the points where you want the breaks, like this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/764015/1046057 (assuming you need a long string like the one you have with no spaces).

Comment: Got another problem now instead... The words that were breaked with the word-wrap: break-word; made the words get split into different parts. Can´t you make them stick togother?

Comment: Ooops. Didn´t do spaces in preview for you... In real life it was a WB and nomatter if you used spaces or not, it continuted...