# Forcing a long line of text (without spaces) to line break according to parent containers static width using CSS

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS: how can I force a long string (without any blank) to be wrapped in XUL and/or HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499137/css-how-can-i-force-a-long-string-without-any-blank-to-be-wrapped-in-xul-and)

Lets say one has the following code:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:1000px">This-is-a-long-line-of-text-without-any-spaces-This-is-a-long-line-of-text-without-any-spaces-This-is-a-long-line-of-text-without-any-spaces-This-is-a-long-line-of-text-without-any-spaces</div>
```

I apologize but stack overflow (according to the preview) does not line break code snippets.

Under most (?) circumstances, the following will cause the container that holds the long line of text to stretch to the full width of the text contained within.

We would like to force this to line break (even mid word) according to the css specified width (width:100px) of the parent container.

Is this possible via a css tag I do not know about?

IE6+ comparability, plus gecko/webkit/opera please.

Comment: For those who are searching the **same solution with bootstrap** there is `text-break` when it is a word without whitespaces, or `text-wrap` when it is a text with whitespaces. [Here is the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/text/#word-break)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Modern (CSS3) answer, that [now works in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/wordwrap):

```
.wrap {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Note that you may need to add `overflow:hidden` and/or `width:100%` to a parent/ancestor element.

---

Old answer:

```
.wrap { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

Comment: will check this within 12 hours and correct answer vote this answer if it does what i need. thank you wholeheartedly.

Comment: IIRC `word-wrap` is supported by all browser. So no need to do all that browser specific stuff.

Comment: @PeeHaa Confirmed on Firefox 43. `word-wrap: break-word` works fine. I don't know what `white-space: pre-wrap` does.

Comment: What if you don't have defined a width for div element? It didn't worked for me unless I specity a width in pixels for the element.

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` does not work in Chrome (54) but `word-wrap: break-word` does.

Comment: Have same issue with Safari 10, does anyone have thoughts on that?

Comment: I can confirm `word-wrap: break-word` is necessary in Chrome v70

Comment: Today in 2019, you could just specify overflow-wrap: break-word;

Comment: `space: pre-wrap` has a different effect - quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):
_Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <br> elements._
`word-wrap: break-word` is the solution, but will require a fixed size, possibly `overflow: hidden` on the container or it's ancestor.

Comment: To add onto what @Jacobski said, `overflow-wrap` is the new standard

Comment: For tailwindcss users use: `break-all`

Answer (score 15):

A combination of `word-wrap` and `word-break` may solve this for you. See [How to force a line break in a loooooong word in a DIV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058866/how-to-force-a-line-break-in-a-loooooong-word-in-a-div) (possible dupe)