# 5 divs in one row, can't align them in one line

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I'm quite new on web development.  I'm struggling with this question for a while.  Now I post my question(s) here.

The souce code is as linked: [Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/hrhktkbzyy/xnt19y1j/1/)

The HTML:

```
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="main" class="clearfix">

        <ul class="ranklist" id = "ranklist">
      <li class="ranklistitem font-size-0">
        <div class="itemnumber divinline"> <span class="helper"></span>1</div>
        <div class="userprofile divinline"><img class="profileimg" src=""/></div>
        <div class="nameandcredit divinline">
          <div class="username">SteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteveSteve</div>
          <div class="credit">I'm description</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ranktitle divinline">Total:</div>
        <div class="usercredit divinline">1000</div>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    background: #aaaaaa;    
}

body {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
    font-family: "PingHei", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Arial, "Microsoft YaHei";
    font-weight: lighter;
}
#wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
}
#main {
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
}

div, ul, p {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: #ffd8d0;
}

.rewarddes
{
    margin-top:10px;
    display:block;
    color:#ffdcc5;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:87.5%;
}
.ranklistitem {
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #faa559;
    font-size:87.5%;
}
.font-size-0 {

}
.divinline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.helper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.itemnumber {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background:#aa8800;
    width: 6%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
.userprofile {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background:#228845;
}
.profileimg {
    height: 36px;
    width: 36px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-top-left-radius: 50%;
    border-top-right-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
}
.nameandcredit {
    height: 60px;
    width: 45%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    background:#342389
}
.username {
    height: 55%;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.credit {
    height: 25%;
    font-size: 66.7%;
    text-align: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    color:#fdff6e;
}

.username:before, .credit:after {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
}

.iconaward {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 20px;
    width: 14px;
}
.ranktitle {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 15%;
    background:#cd8912;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0.125em;
}
.usercredit {
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background:#ff0000;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

I have 2 questions based on the linked(or above) code.

1. The 5 container div's width was set as:
   `.itemnumber`  6%, `.userprofile`  14%, `.nameandcredit`  45%,  `.ranktitle`  15%,  `.usercredit`  20%.  So **in total they are 100%**.  But as you see, the last one `.usercredit` is not in the same line and there're margins between each div, which is not what I want.
2. for the `.username`, I have set `overflow:hidden`, but as you see, when there's a large string, the .username was totally disappeared.  If there're spaces in the string, it will only hide the overflow part and show the front part.  I want to know what's the problem?

I know it's a little bit messed up of a lot code here.  But my question is as listed as above.  Thanks in advance for any kind suggestion.

Comment: the paddings make them larger than the percentage you're setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the spacing, you have two problems:

1. Implicit spaces between `inline-block` elements, and
2. Defining widths for elements with padding.

Regarding username overflow, you have one issue:

3. Default word wrapping behavior is to wrap the whole word to the next line. You need to change that behavior.

Let's take a look at each of them:

---

**Implicit Spaces**

The problem is that your `div`s have a `display: inline-block;` style. Elements displayed as an `inline-block` have any white-space between them converted to a single space.

[See the "Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements" article on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more information on how to overcome this.

One fix, for instance, is to have the `li` element that is wrapping the `div`s to have a 0 font-size, and reset a non-zero font size to its children, e.g. in your CSS:

```
.font-size-0 {
    font-size: 0;
}
.font-size-0 > * {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Any of the links outlined in the link above would work; for example, removing spaces and newlines between your closing tag and opening tag would do the same thing, without forcing you to set and reset the `font-size`.

---

**Widths for elements with padding**

In CSS, a `width` is defined by default for an element to include only its content area (`box-sizing: content-box;` by default) and not the padding. Set the `box-sizing` to `border-box` and you'll be all set.

E.g.

```
.font-size-0 > div {
    box-sizing: border-size;
}
```

---

**Properly wrapping a single word without spaces**

See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499137/css-how-can-i-force-a-long-string-without-any-blank-to-be-wrapped-in-xul-and) to see how to address the issue. You will basically need to add this to your `.username` rule:

```
.username {
    ...
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

---

**[Final Result jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnt19y1j/3/)**

Comment: Hi EyasSH, thank you very much for your quick response and the great answer!  Just want to ask, the second quesion.  If I have a long string as I posted above:  'SteveSteveSteve...', It will be totally hidden.  If I change it to: 'Steve Steve...', It will show the front part of the white space.  Do you have any idea of this problem?

Comment: @Vigor, I just edited my answer to show how to fix that issue :)

Comment: Thank you EysaSH, many thanks.  You saved me a lot of time.  Cheers.