# Inline Span Bug(?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Spending most of my time in a backend, frontend isn't really my forte and my skills in debugging are next to none for it (aside from F12 trial-and-error).

I have created a list (for Google Maps purposes) from the data entered backend side.

As you can see, **treybake2** has the email of: **t.taylor@domain.co.uk** - 21 characters.

**treybake** has an email of **t.taylor@some-domain.co.uk** - 26 characters.

Yet, the latter of the options (which has the longer email) seems to wrap how I'd expect whereas the shorter email address drops to a new line entirely.

Here is the markup for the tel/email section:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 no-padding">
    <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">
        <i class="fas fa-phone fa-rotate-90"></i>
        <span><?php echo $dealer->tel; ?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 no-padding">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <span><?php echo $dealer->email; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see by the class names, it uses Bootstrap.

Here is, hopefully, the relevant CSS:

```
#dealer-list {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    height: 350px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 20px 15px
}

#dealer-list li {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 15px
}

#dealer-list li div {
    margin: 5px 0
}

div.no-padding {
    padding: 0
}
```

I'm for the most-part, a scrub when it comes to frontend, and I can't really set up xdebug for this kinda thing xD

So, how do I begin to try and debug my span? Logically, if any were to drop to a new line, surely it would be **treybake2**? Why is the other way round?

Edit:

Forgot to put in my desired output: **treybake** is how I want all emails to be displayed.

[image]

Comment: Because a dash (`-`) is a breaking point.

Comment: @Roy huh.. that's weird.. why is not just "here's the string?" xD OK.. so how does one resolve? Or where do I go to find the answer?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force a long string without any blank to be wrapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499137/how-can-i-force-a-long-string-without-any-blank-to-be-wrapped), assuming you want the email to wrap (you don't actually say in your question *hint*)

Comment: @HereticMonkey see my edit ;)

Comment: Then that dupe should work. It should ask if that question's answers answer your question...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yee done and done, will take your word for it, this frontend bs honestly confuses me to heck xD