# React - Material UI Typography how to break long string to multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using ReactJS and the components library called MaterialUI. I'm having an issue with the Typography component.

What happens is that if I write a long text it exceed its container and doesn't go on a new line:

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

function Homepage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <React.Fragment>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Container fixed>
          <Typography variant="h1" component="h2" align="center">
            123 456 789 qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm
          </Typography>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(Homepage);
```

below an image:

[image]

This happens in the mobile mode and also in desktop mode.

Do you know how to fix this behavior? I would like the long words will be split on a new line if the maximum width of the container has been reached.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Solution**

Use **word-wrap**, it works for Material-UI's Typography.

```
wordWrap: "break-word"
```

Ref: [QA: wrap long string without any blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499137/how-can-i-force-a-long-string-without-any-blank-to-be-wrapped)

---

**Demo**

```
<Typography
  variant="h1"
  component="h2"
  align="center"
  style={{ wordWrap: "break-word" }}
>
  123 456 789 qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmdfsafasfasfadfaf
</Typography>
```

Try it online:
[image: Edit wizardly-noether-n9435]

Answer (score 1):

I came across this and it's a great fix. I ended up adding this in globally to my typography. If you need this then simply add keikai's answer to your createMuiTheme.

```
//theme.jsx or theme.tsx
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from '@material-ui/core/styles';


let theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: { 
    MuiTypography: { 
      root: { 
        wordWrap: "break-word"
      }
   } 
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 24-11-2021  createMuiTheme deprecated
new version that work:

```
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiTypography: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    wordWrap: "break-word"
                },
            },
        },
        MuiCard: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    width: "auto",
                    margin: 10,

                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```