# html - problem with word wrapping

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have some text in div, and I want it to wrap to fit document width (without any scrolls!). I don't want to have word-break, like div {word-wrap: break-word;}

For example (this is what I want to get):

```
hello world! today is a 
good day.
```

But not:

```
hello world! today is a  good day.
```

or:

```
hello world! today is a go
od day.
```

Comment: Umm. ChrisW has edited your question to try to make some sense of it, but it sounds like you are asking for what is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, is it just this?

```
<div style="width:200px">hello world! today is a good day.</div>
```

Comment: No. Width of the window can be changes as user resizes it. So, there is no fixed width. For example, if this lines are bounds:
|                        |
wonderful wonderful 
wonderful
So you see, because there is no space for 3-rd wonderful , it goes to second line

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks everyone! I had too much &nbsp; and that affected the way text is wrapped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `<wbr>` tag could help you. 
This tag allow the browser to insert a line break where it's positioned, 
"if the browser want" .

[This](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEbreak-word.html) is a page were the IEbreak behavior is documented, you can take It as a model to do some debugging.

And if you want to fire-up jQuery to script-inject `<wbr>` in your html [here you can se an example from John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/injecting-word-breaks-with-javascript/).

You can read a complete reference about It [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html)

[A similar topic was discussed on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/who-has-solved-the-long-word-breaks-my-div-problem-hint-not-stackoverflow).