# lines not breaking in a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am probably missing soemthing very simple, but the following is a comment posted on in my rails app and if the content is too long..then it doesnot wrap automatically withing the paragraph and overflows onto the page.

The content of the paragraph is generated by Redcloth, though this particular paragraph does not contain any textile markup and I doubt the final result has anything to do with textile..I am probably missing a very basic css property somewhere.

```
<div class="comment append-bottom ui-widget-content normal-pad" id="comment">



<div class="user-image right-mar-small go-left" id="user_image"><a href="/users/user9"><img src="/assets/images/users/14/small.jpg?1285884662" class="profile-image" alt="avatar"></a></div>

    <div >
      <p >really really long paragraph ksdjfklajdskfjsdaklfjlaksdjflkdjsafkljasdfkljasdklfjs;lafj;klajsdf;kljdsakfljsa;ldkfjldaksjfklasjdf;kljadsfkljsad;kfjsa;ldkfj;adksljf;lkadjsfk;lajsdf;lkjsad;fkjads;lkfj;ladksjf;lkasdjf;lkdjas;flkjads;lkfjs;adklfj;ladkjf;lkdajsf;klsajdf;lksjadf;lkjsad;kfjsa;ldkfj;kladsjflkdsajfkljdask;lfjkldasjflk;ajdsflkadsjflkjdflkjadslk;fj;ldksajf;lkasdjf;lkjadsfk;ljads;klfjdask;lfj;ladkjf;lasdjf;</p>
    </div>
    <div id="" class="prepend-top">


      <span>Like </span>  
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you do not have any space characters in the long word. Try the solution mentioned in the 3rd comment.

[How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/who-has-solved-the-long-word-breaks-my-div-problem-hint-not-stackoverflow)