# Is it possible to enable auto-hyphenation in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, hyphenation

My client has requested to enable auto-hyphenation on this page: http://carlosdinizart.com/biography/ , and I realized I've never actually seen it done on a web-page.

Is it possible to set up auto-hyphenation in an HTML document with just HTML/CSS? If not - what are the options?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/320184/104380

Answer (score 46, accepted):

CSS3 provides some support for this. Source: http://drublic.de/blog/css3-auto-hyphenation-for-text-elements/
You can check the w3c documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-text-20110901/#hyphenation

CSS3 adds six properties to the list of useful thing. These are:

- The most important one is `hyphens`.
- You can add dictionary-files with `hyphenate-resource` so the browser has a better chance to render your text with the right hyphenation.
- `hyphenate-before` sets a minimum number of characters before the hyphenation.
- `hyphenate-after` does the same as `hyphenate-before` but for characters after the hyphenation.
- `hyphenate-lines` defines about how many lines a hyphenated word is written at a maximum.
  with `hyphenate-character` you can specify which HTML-entity should be used, e.g. `\2010`.

The main property of this stack is `hyphens`. It accepts one of three values: `none`, `manual` or `auto`. The default one is manual, where you can set hyphens via `&shy;`. `auto` it the better one for continuous text while words get split if possible and available. And `none` does not hyphenate at all even if there is a character set for a possible line break in a certain word.

**Update:**

Browser support information here: http://caniuse.com/css-hyphens

Comment: Interesting. Any information on how widely supported this is?

Comment: I have updated with a link that lists the browser support for this

Comment: I'm disappointed in both Chrome and Opera. Kudos to IE and Firefox. Also, an up-vote for a property I hadn't heard of or come across.

Comment: respect, that the properties `hyphenate-*` are not part of CSS Standard anymore.

Comment: Looks like `hyphenate-resource` is not a part of spec anymore. And no browser supports it. So we are tied to built-in dictionaries or third-party JS solutions like [Hyphenopoly](https://github.com/mnater/Hyphenopoly)

Answer (score 16):

An option is to insert [soft hyphens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) into the text in places where it *may* be broken. The soft hyphen is represented by the entity `&shy;` in HTML. You may find libraries/tools that can prepare text automatically with `&shy;`s in the right places, otherwise you'll have to do it manually.

Comment: Teehee I like the way it is abbreviated. Don't be so shy!

Comment: Yup, `&shy;` is one of my favorite HTML tags. (Did I really just say this? Man, am I nerdy. ;o))

Comment: @deceze, I think, you wanted to say "HTML entities", not "tags". ;)

Comment: The problem with this is that copying and pasting text with &shy; will copy the soft hyphen character too. It may also mess up Ctrl+F in some browsers.

Answer (score 9):

To deal with one page that has fixed width for text, the practical move would be to add a couple of SOFT HYPHEN characters (U+00AD), using the entity reference `&shy;` if you find it more comfortable than entering the (invisible) character itself. You can rather quickly find out which words need to be hyphenated to produce a good result.

In a more complex case (several pages, flexible width), use a preprocessor, or server-side code, or client-side code that adds soft hyphens. The client-side approach is simplest and can be applied independently of server-side technologies and authoring tools. Beware that automatic hyphenation may go wrong and needs some help: the language(s) of the text need to be indicated in markup (or otherwise, depending on the library used).

At the minimum, you could just put the attributes `lang=en class=hyphenate` into the `<body>` tag and the following code in the `head` part:

```
<script 
  src="http://hyphenator.googlecode.com/svn/tags/Version%204.0.0/Hyphenator.js">
</script>
<script>Hyphenator.run();</script>
```

Demo: http://bytelevelbooks.com/code/javascript/hyphenation.html (flexible-width text, with just maximum width set, so you can test it varying the browser window width).

Comment: Apparently google no longer hosts `Hyphenator.js`. Is that the same thing now on [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/Hyphenator)?

Answer (score 4):

At present my css for `<p>` is

```
p   {
    font-style: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: 0px ;
    margin-right: .5em ;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-indent: 1em;
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-hyphens: auto;
    -moz-hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
    -o-hyphens: auto;
    word-break:break-word;
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

This doesn't work for Chrome 39 on Mac.  Known not to work on Opera.
Works for Firefox, iOS Safari.

This is NOT foolproof:  Narrow columns (under 6 words) are ugly, but overall it makes the layout look far more like properly set type.