# Avoid unnatural word-break

Tags: html, css, word-break

I have a `<h1>` title with a long word, such as the following. The browser width depends on the device of course, but I've noticed that on one of my devices, it looks like this:

[image]

which is not a very nice word-breaking.

**How to ask the browser to do "nicer" breakings instead?**

Example: Internationali-sation or -tion or -on but not `n` alone in the next line.

Here is how to reproduce the problem (I've hardcoded `260px` here just to reproduce what I've seen on my device, but this is not really hardcoded in my code):

```css
.a { width: 260px; background-color: yellow; }
h1 { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
<h1>Internationalisation</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually insert soft hyphen `&shy;` which is visible only on break. It suggests a place where the browser might break that word. Its something like `<wbr>` but with hyphen. Something like this:

```css
h1 { word-wrap: break-word; }
.small { width:260px; }
```

```html
<h1 class="small">Internationali&shy;sation</h1>
<h1>Internationali&shy;sation</h1>
```

There are a lot of problems with automatic word breaking which usually depends on browser dictionary ([hyhphens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) can be used) or external scripts. You can also read more about it in another questions like [Is it possible to enable auto-hyphenation in HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937591/is-it-possible-to-enable-auto-hyphenation-in-html-css).

Answer (score 4):

The [`<wbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr) tag exists for this purpose.

> The **HTML `<wbr>` element** represents a word break opportunity—a
> position within text where the browser may optionally break a line,
> though its line-breaking rules would not otherwise create a break at
> that location.

```css
.a { width: 260px; background-color: yellow; }
h1 { word-wrap: break-word; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
<h1>Internationali<wbr>sation</h1>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can also add a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) to the word, though that might cause odd behavior when trying to copy the string. (We get some questions here on Stack Overflow where code doesn't work because it contains a hidden zero-width space.)

Answer (score -1):

Well you could prevent breaking altogether...

```css
.a { width: 260px; background-color: yellow; }
h1 { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
<h1>Internationalisation</h1>
</div>
```

Or. set spans inside your content to denote where breaking should occur. This is a big ass word, not two separate words so the browser is clueless unless you educate it

```css
.a { width: 260px; background-color: yellow; }
h1 { word-wrap: break-word; }
h1 span { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
<h1>International<span>isation</span></h1>
</div>
```