# stop div content overflowing?

Tags: html, css

If I have a `div` with a specific width, and it contains continuous content, then it will overflow. Is there a way to make it break the word and move part of it to the next line? e.g:

```
<div style="float:left;width:200px;">thiscontentwilloverflowthedivbecuaseitdoesnthaveanyspacesinit</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is kinda like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div

Answer (score 11, accepted):

add the following css:

```
overflow:hidden; word-wrap:break-word
```

word-wrap is css3 so it won't work with every browser

Answer (score 0):

use

`overflow-wrap: break-word;`

and here is it's compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap