# how to break long word in Span?(using Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: css

I'm using Twitter bootstrap in my site and I'm having span which may contain long word and I need to break it. I use this Css but not working? what's problem?

```
.fidDivComment {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to add this to your CSS for that span

```
span {
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-all;

  /* Non standard for webkit */
  word-break: break-word;

  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

See [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/) for an explanation.

Comment: You should either hyphenate words properly, or break strings arb itrarily if you have special content for which that is appropriate. Doing both on same content is wrong.

Comment: Jukka, if you read the article I linked to, you need all those CSS properties for the best browser support.

Comment: The hyphens bit is optional - I omitted this for my use case (long emails)

Comment: Will this respect rules according to the meta page language such as putting hyphens between syllables?

Answer (score 4):

The questions stated this:

> (using Twitter Bootstrap)

so the bootstrap fix is this: `@include hyphens;`    this bootstrap out of the box mixin will add  `word-wrap: break-word;`
this mixin is exist under this path:

```
/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins/_vendor-prefixes.scss
```