# Long word wrap in nested tables

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to wrap a long word. I have seen this post : [How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)

It works great in a simple case like this :

```
.wrapWords
{
    white-space: pre;           /* CSS 2.0 */
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS 2.1 */
    white-space: pre-line;      /* CSS 3.0 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla */
    white-space: -hp-pre-wrap;  /* HP Printers */
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE 5+ */

}

<!-- This wraps correctly -->
<div style="width:145px;">
    <div class="wrapWords" style="width:100%;">
        <a href="#">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
    </div>
<div>
```

But my case has two nested tables like this :

```
<!-- This doesn't work -->
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:145px;">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:100%;">
                        <div class="wrapWords" style="width:100%;">
                            <a href="#">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can test this code here http://jsfiddle.net/ZmnQ6/4/

Comment: Do you want to wrap words (properly), or to bre ak the m? Your wording suggests the former, your code the latter. Two very different questions, with very different answers.

Comment: I want a very long word like "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" to wrap inside it's container without changing his width.

Comment: “AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA” is not a word, at least not a word that you could properly wrap (with hyphenation).

Comment: For instance "anticonstitutionnellement" is a long french word. If I place it in a small container, I don't won't the container to resize. I rather see the word cut at an arbitrary position.

Comment: Well, then you should specify that you want to break words. But I don’t see why you would do that instead of proper word division.

Comment: How could the browser know how to divide properly a word without any spaces or hyphens ?

Comment: In many ways. But as I wrote, this is a different question. Try searching for *hyphenation* among questions at SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

table is taking the `table-layout: auto;` by default so as per contents increase the width also increases so you need to set table-layout to fixed.

```
table{
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmnQ6/6/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 completely different algorithms for table layout: with or without `table-layout: fixed`

Former will adapt width of cells to the author's will
Latter will adapt width of cells to the content (the relative quantity/width/whatever of content in cells)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZmnQ6/7/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<!-- This wraps correctly -->
<div style="width:145px;">
    <div class="wrapWords" style="width:100%;">
        <a href="#">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</a>
    </div>
<div>

<!-- This doesn't work -->
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:145px;">
            <table style="width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:130px;">
                        <div class="wrapWords" style="width:inherit; display:inline-block;">
                            <a href="#">BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**The Logic:**

The `div` and `td` have different `display` characteristics. You need to make your `div` which is nested inside the `td` to change its `display` to, for instance here `inline-block` with a fixed `width` to achive what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works in your case because you have set the width of the outer <td> to a fixed width (130px).

Comment: Yes. That is what mentioned at the end of my answer - @Michael