# Weird Bootstrap 3 text-wrapping issue with IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, word-wrap

I have a very basic alert box as follows:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top: 0.25em;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> 
            You can send us files that end in: .jpg .gif .png .bmp .psd .pdf .doc 
            .docx .ppt .pptx .xls .xlsx .vsd .txt .tiff.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In IE, the text portion ".vsd .txt .tiff." somehow ends up outside the bounds of the box.

Below is a jsfiddle, resize the view panel to see the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/7um8L6yz/

Do I have to manually force word wrap specifically for IE?

Comment: **What version** of IE?

Comment: @cvrebert I was able to confirm the issue on versions 6 through 11. Further, it appears to repro on http://remote.modern.ie as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer appears (versions 6 through 11) to be confusing the `.foo<space>` pattern as one that shouldn't allow a break. To confirm this I created a simple script that replicated the pattern a thousand times:

```js
for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ) {
    document.body.appendChild(
        // Note the trailing space after .wut
        document.createTextNode( ".wut " )
    );
}
```

Sure enough, Internet Explorer generates lateral overflow rather than wrapping the text at the at the most appropriate instance of white-space. I work on the Internet Explorer team and will open up an issue for our team to investigate further whether this is intentional or not.

You could follow each extension with a comma (*.foo, .bar*):

```html
<p class="alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top: 0.25em;">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> 
    You can send us files that end in: .jpg, .gif, .png, .bmp, .psd, .pdf, .doc, 
    .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .xls, .xlsx, .vsd, .txt, .tiff.
</p>
```

[This will successfully wrap as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Lrz3wo/1/). This does add to the verbosity of the text however.

Alternatively, you can explicitly instruct IE to break more often:

```css
.alert { word-break: break-all }
```

This appears to resolve the issue you're experiencing, however you may find that it breaks *too soon*. The only other alternative would be to modify the contents such that you explicitly state that a break may occur after each extension:

```js
// Run after document has been populated with all .alert-info elements
$( ".alert-info" ).contents().each(function ( i, o ) {
    if ( o.nodeType === 3 ) {
        $( o ).replaceWith(function () {
            return o.nodeValue.replace( /\s+/g, " &shy;" );
        });
    }
});
```

Granted, this isn't ideal, but unfortunately it's all we can do for the time being.

Comment: You IE DevRel folks are... **extremely proactive**!

Comment: @cvrebert We aim to please :)

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be caused by IE interpreting this part of the string:
`.jpg .gif .png .bmp .psd .pdf .doc .docx .ppt .pptx .xls .xlsx .vsd .txt .tiff.` 
as one word. I'm not sure why it is doing this but inserting `&shy;` after the different file extensions in this part does allow it to wrap everything properly.

`.alert { word-break: break-all }` seems to break even in the middle of the word but it definitely seems easier to do.

See this post on `&shy;`
[How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)

Answer (score 0):

updated a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7um8L6yz/12/)

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4"> <pre class=" alert alert-info" role="alert" style="margin-top:0.25em;">
<p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i> You can send us files that end in:     </p>            
.jpg .gif .png .bmp .psd .pdf .doc .docx .ppt .pptx .xls .xlsx .vsd .txt .tiff.</pre>

 </div>
</div>
```