# How do I avoid 1 long word from messing up my comment section?

Tags: html, cpu-word

So I have a comment social thing I created. Basically what happens is that if someone types a really long word, I mean like no spaces whatsoever, the new div created won't be able to contain it, so it runs off the page.

Here is a live example:

```css
.content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="color:#B404AE; font-weight:bold;">'.$name. '</div>
<div class="content">'VerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongword'</div>
<br
/>
```

JSbin version: http://output.jsbin.com/tilomacopo

How do I avoid this problem. Is there a way to split this word up, if there is no spaces in it? I'm not sure what I should google, or even how to word this, which is the main problem. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Try adding _word-wrap: break-word;_ in your _.content_ CSS rule

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with changing the default word wrapping behavior is that if the user is typing normally, their line may break in the middle of a word, which feels very unnatural.

I would consider instead putting a scrollbar on the div if the text gets too long. The way to do that is by giving it the `overflow: auto` CSS property.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" style="color:#B404AE; font-weight:bold;">'.$name. '</div>
<div class="content">'VerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongwordVerylongword'</div>
<br/>
<div class="content" style="color:#B404AE; font-weight:bold;">'.$name. '</div>
<div class="content">'Shorter, normal words break and wrap normally when they reach the end of the div that they're in.'</div>
<br/>
```

Edit: I just learned that if you use `word-wrap: break-word`, then only words that are too long will be broken up, so that might be a better solution. A full list of word-wrap properties is available [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap).

Answer (score 1):

If you add the style `word-break: break-all` to the container that contains that text string – it will force the string to wrap when it exceeds the width of that container.

Update: `word-wrap: break-word` is a much better rule to use.

[Updated jsbin](http://jsbin.com/cuxuzodabe/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that adds a space or dash after certain characters if the comment is too long. There are some other possibilities as discussed here: [How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)