# Cannot get my margins correctly

Tags: php, css

I have been working on a contact system - I got it to work, replies, everything - But the margins are way out of wack - see pic - Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong? It is also centered and I want it to the left.

I have listed my index.php and styles.css below. I have to integrate it into an existing website  - www.londonontariomortgages.ca/blog.html - So I am thinking of doing iFrame - However, with it not creating a new line when past the margin it looks dumb.

[image]

index.php

```
<?php require_once 'php/connect.php'; require_once 'php/functions.php'; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YouTube Comment System Series</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en-US">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/global.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p>
        <div class="page-container">
            <?php 
                get_total();
                require_once 'php/check_com.php';
            ?>
            <form action="" method="post" class="main">
                <label>enter a brief comment</label>
                <textarea class="form-text" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                <br />
                <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="new_comment" value="post">
            </form>
            <?php get_comments(); ?>
        </div>
    </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

styles.php

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700);

/* resets */
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-family:'Calibri', sans-serif;
    outline:none;
}

/* Animations */
@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}

/* body, html */
html, body {
    background-color:#edf1f5;
}

/* content */
.page-container {
    width:80%;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100vh;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:50px 10px 0px 10px;
}
.comment {
    width:45%;
    height:auto;
    padding:7px 23px;
    margin:0px auto;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:left;
}
.child {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:30px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
.child-comments {
    border-left:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
}

form.main {
    width:45%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5px;
}
    .form-input {
        border:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
        width:50%;
        padding:4px 7px;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:24px;
        resize:none;
    }
    .form-text {
        border:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
        width:100%;
        padding:4px 7px;
        margin-top:5px;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:24px;
        resize:none;
        transition:ease 0.2s all;
        outline:none !important;
    }
        .form-text-error {
            border-color:rgba(237,28,36,0.7);
            animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            backface-visibility: hidden;
            perspective: 1000px;
        }
        .form-text:focus {
            border-color:rgba(0,114,188,0.7);
        }
    .form-submit {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        border:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.3);
        cursor:pointer;
        padding:5px 13px;
        margin-top:5px;
    }

/* fonts */
.user, .time {
    display:inline-block;
}
.user {
    font-size:13px;
    color:#0072bc;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-break: break-all;
    line-height:17px;
}
.time {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#b2b1b1;
    transition:ease 0.2s all;
}
    .comment:hover .time {
        color:#767676;
    }
.comment-text {
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:17px;
    color:#222;
    margin:0px 10px;
}
a {
    font-size:11.2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#222;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:ease 0.3s all;
}
a:hover {
    color:#0072bc;
}
    .link-reply {
        color:#767676;
        margin-left:20px;
    }

h1 {
    width:45%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px auto;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
}

label {
    font-size:13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the html that forms after this php code runs in browser. That will help in figuring out this issue -> "with it not creating a new line when past the margin it looks dumb."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent long words from breaking my div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div)

Comment: Looks to me as this question is not about margins but the super-long words breaking the width of their containers...

Answer (score 1):

See updated CSS, I removed `margin: auto` from the `.page-container` and `form.main` and ".comment"

That was causing the centering of form on the page instead of default left alignment.

Add this CSS for fixing the text not wrapping issue

```
.comment-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #222;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Your comments do not wrap because there is no space in them. So to break elements with no space in them, you need to add `word-break: break-all` property to break them explicitly.

In ideal world scenario, your comments will definitely have spaces in them and you wont need it(word-break), but the testers(testing your website ) will test it with any dummy data, so you need to be prepared for that and apply fix generally for this issue.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700);

/* resets */

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
  outline: none;
}


/* Animations */

@keyframes shake {
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%,
  50%,
  70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%,
  60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}


/* body, html */

html,
body {
  background-color: #edf1f5;
}


/* content */

.page-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.comment {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 7px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.child {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.child-comments {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
}

form.main {
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.form-input {
  border: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  width: 50%;
  padding: 4px 7px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  resize: none;
}

.form-text {
  border: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 7px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px;
  resize: none;
  transition: ease 0.2s all;
  outline: none !important;
}

.form-text-error {
  border-color: rgba(237, 28, 36, 0.7);
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36, .07, .19, .97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.form-text:focus {
  border-color: rgba(0, 114, 188, 0.7);
}

.form-submit {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.3);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 13px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}


/* fonts */

.user,
.time {
  display: inline-block;
}

.user {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #0072bc;
  text-decoration: none;
  word-break: break-all;
  line-height: 17px;
}

.time {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #b2b1b1;
  transition: ease 0.2s all;
}

.comment:hover .time {
  color: #767676;
}

.comment-text {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: #222;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}

a {
  font-size: 11.2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: ease 0.3s all;
}

a:hover {
  color: #0072bc;
}

.link-reply {
  color: #767676;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

h1 {
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
}

label {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>YouTube Comment System Series</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en-US">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/global.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>
    <div class="page-container">
      <?php 
                get_total();
                require_once 'php/check_com.php';
            ?>
      <form action="" method="post" class="main">
        <label>enter a brief comment</label>
        <textarea class="form-text" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" class="form-submit" name="new_comment" value="post">
      </form>
      <?php get_comments(); ?>
    </div>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it - However the comments are still not coming in at multiple lines - http://londonontariomortgages.ca/a/index.php  - Would you mind taking a quick look? I am newbie at this stuff, thought I have come a long way in a week

Comment: Add word-break: break-all; on comment-text   .comment-text {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 17px;
    color: #222;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    word-break: break-all;
}  See updated answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Capricorn thanks will do just now. Please give me some time. :)

Comment: Thank you - I really appreciate all of the help - If I could trouble you for one more suggestion - I am hoping to have all of the comments straight down my page - so right under the text box - http://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/a/index.php    -    My eventual aim is to merge it into http://londonontariomortgages.ca/blog.html so that people can comment on the blog. Do you mind taking one more look?

Comment: @MarkMitchell Remove  margin: 0px auto;  from the .comment div too  and change the padding : 7px 23px to     padding: 7px 0;

Comment: basically   margin: 0 auto; is centering everything horizontally on your page. If its not required dont use it

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma - Thanks so much!! That worked :) Now off to integrate - wish me luck :)

Comment: @NanditaAroraSharma - Quick question with this field - if you a minute - I used iframe to merge it into my existing site - http://www.londonontariomortgages.ca/Blogs/blog_%20june_%2013/blog_june13_2018.html - but when I did the size of box and the comments shrunk to much lower - Do you know which line I would change in the css to fix this? I have the iframe set at 100% width