# text-align justify bug on ie internet explorer and android

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, text-align, justify

I have a very bad justify effect on internet explorer and android for my wordpress content : for some lines I got big spaces between words and suddenly a tiny space between the last two words of the line

It works fine on other browsers ie chrome/firefox/safari.

Platform : Wordpress 3.5 + Visual composer plugin

Someone got an idea ?

Here is the content :
http://www.arkama.fr/offres/sap/assistance-technique/

It is visible on the line •La recherche et l’identification de

```
<ul style="text-align: justify;">
<li style="text-align: justify;">La bonne <strong>qualification</strong> du besoin client ;</li>
</ul>
<ul style="text-align: justify;">
<li style="text-align: justify;">La <strong>recherche</strong> et <strong>l’identification</strong> de ressources disponibles et adaptées ;</li>
</ul>
<ul style="text-align: justify;">
<li style="text-align: justify;">La <strong>validation du profil</strong> et des compétences de ce dernier <strong>par des entretiens techniques, de personnalité</strong> et <strong>d’anglais</strong> ;        
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post which specific versions of the browser you are having issues with such as ie8, ie9, etc

Comment: It is happening with all main ie version : ie9/8/7

Comment: a nice answer concerning justified text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315845/should-i-avoid-using-text-align-justify#answer-657528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some hidden hex characters in your source code cause this issue. In IE non-breaking-space-characters are not stretched in justified text.

The Developer Tools in Chrome reveal the HTML code which these characters generate:

[image: Element inspection by Chrome Dev Tools]

A hex editor (HxD in my case) lifts the lid on some hidden characters in your source code (`00` and `20` are OK, but a `A0` renders a `&nbsp;`, which causes the problems in your case):

[image: Source code view in HxD]

You could try to copy/paste your code using a text editor like notepad++ to get rid of these characters.
Using Dreamweaver, which has has a built-in-feature to show hidden characters (view > code view options > hidden characters), everything worked fine in IE after deleting these characters.

[image: source code in Dreamwaever]